# Delete multiple lines from cursor upwards

Tags: cut-copy-paste

If you have a text like:

```
word1 word2
word3 word4 word5
```

You can put your cursor over first `d`, type `2D` and be left with:

```
wor
```

But you can't do the deletion upwards from second line with `2d^` or `2d0`. Closest I found was `3db` which removes based on number of words not lines.

Any equivalent of `D` command only upwards, **without** resorting to visual mode?

**Edit:** Put your cursor over `w` of `word4`. If you type `2db` you end up with `word1 word4 word5`. If you type `dv2k`, you end with the same. What I want is just `word4 word5`.

Comment: @BLayer added edit, your solution is similar to `db`.

Comment: @BLayer works perfectly. Please post answer with explanation so I can upvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret weapon is `v`. Specifically, you can convert a command that by default operates in a linewise manner to characterwise operation by typing `v` after the command and before the motion, e.g. compare `dk` to `dvk`.

With that in hand we just need to identify the (normally linewise) command that, used in conjunction with `v`, gets the desired effect.

A good motion candidate is `-`...

```
-  <minus>      [count] lines upward, on the first non-blank
                character |linewise|.
```

With the cursor on the "w" of "word4" `d-` will delete everything on the current and preceding lines. But insert `v` in the middle for `dv-` and, voila, that will delete everything on the same line that *precedes* that "w" and the entirety of the preceding line.

And just FYI, you can use `ctrl-v` in place of `v` and then you'll go from linewise to blockwise operation.

Comment: Perfect. What's the motion candidate for forward deletion? instead of `D` what can I use to delete everything from cursor and next line with `dv`

Comment: Did you try `+`...you know, that thing that is the opposite of `-` ;) ... (To be fair, because of the way lines are navigated you'll need to add `2` in there: `d2v+`.)

Comment: Yup, already tried. Not working as expected. Try putting cursor on `w` of word2, and delete everything and next line.

Comment: Yes, that's what I tested and it works (deletes word2 and all of following line). You need there to be an empty line below the two target lines. I'm not sure off the top of my head how to do it at the end of the file.

Comment: What about just `d}`?

Comment: Yup, `d}` and `d{` are helpful too. I noticed if you use `dvG`, the last line won't get deleted either and the only option is `d}`. With `dvgg` however it works just fine. Might wanna include bracket versions in your answer too for anyone searching.

Comment: Sorry...forget that...I screwed up. Still, the results aren't the same. `d{` deletes one more line than `dv-`. Plus it won't work in the middle of a paragraph unlike `dv-`...the whole beginning part of the paragraph will get deleted. (Same problem going down, too, of course.)

Comment: Also, `{` and `}` motions are much more well known than the other things. I may, time permitting (right now it's sacktime), add `d2v+` to my answer but leave brackets out except for, _maybe_,  `d}` as a solution to end of file situation.